# Download Image From A Source And Reupload

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading

I am trying to create a simple script that downloads an image from another website, and reuploads it to my own website. The name of the picture its downloading will be the same as whats its uploading. I also need two separate ones working on the same page.

PHP:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://test.com/<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>.png';
$img = '/1/<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>.png';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
?>

<?php
$url = 'http://test.com/<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>.png';
$img = '/2/<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>.png';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
?>
```

Comment: can u please be clear about two seperate ones you need.. Do u need two same images on the page??

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

```
copy('http://somesite.com/path/to/file.png', '/my/server/path/to/file.png');
```

one liner.

More specific to your scenario:

```
$file_name = $_POST['name'].'png';
$file_url = 'http://test.com/'.$file_name;
$save_sources = array('/1/','/2/'); //add as many as you want
foreach( $save_sources as $save_source ){
    copy($file_url, $save_source.$file_name);
}
```